# What can be the reason to use global structure's pointer as a thread local storage

Tags: c, thread-local-storage

```
typedef struct Test
{

}Test;

//global struct
Test t;

static __thread *tTLS = &t;
```

Can someone explain what are we trying to achieve with above code? what can be the usecases?

here we have a global structure and pointer to it is used as a TLS (thread local storage). So we anyways have a global structure address with the thread why we may need its pointer again as a TLS?

The example would help.

Comment: Can you provide more context?  What has your research told you so far, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: My initial attempt at some research led me [here](https://maskray.me/blog/2021-02-14-all-about-thread-local-storage), which discusses the uses of static thread local structures in some detail.

Comment: I understand that with TLS each threads gets their own copy of the shared variable.  With primitive data types such as int, char it is intuitive to understand .
But here we have a global structure and pointer to it is used as a TLS. So we anyways have a global structure address with the thread why we may need its pointer as TLS? or please correct if my understanding is not clear.

Comment: Include that information in your question.

Comment: How does this code even compile?  `tTLS` doesn't appear to have a type defined anywhere, just a bunch of qualifiers and a single asterisk.  I assume `tTLS` is supposed to be a pointer to a thread-specific struct of type `Test`.  What is so confusing about that?  There's probably some thread-specific data in `Test` that needs to be different in different threads.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the code fragment you showed is meant to set up the value of `tTLS` for the *initial thread* (the thread whose thread procedure is `main`), only.  In all the other threads, `tTLS` will be changed to point to some other struct.

You could confirm this guess by showing the code of at least one thread procedure other than `main`.